# Loading external SWF files

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using this code to unload a swf file and go back to the main menu.

The main menu loads the external swf files with no trouble but for some reason unloading just doesn't work.

```
var BaseMovie:MovieClip = parent.parent as MovieClip;

FinishButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, RemoveGame );

function RemoveGame(i:MouseEvent):void
{   
    BaseMovie.loader.unload(); //Loads previous movie and unloads current movie.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `BaseMovie` somewhere else (and you are, because you've added it to the display list to make it visible), it won't be destroyed as a result of calling `Loader.unload()`.

To remove `BaseMovie` from the display list, do something like the following:

```
BaseMovie.parent.removeChild(BaseMovie);
```

Note that by convention, variable names start with lowercase. So instead of `BaseMovie`, use `baseMovie`.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Sorry for some odd reason I left out that BaseMovie.loader.unload(); is inside a function. The function is triggered at the end of the game. Do I need to remove the BaseMovie inside that function? I've edited my question to show the code.

Comment: Yeah, `BaseMovie.parent.removeChild(BaseMovie);` should be in `RemoveGame`.

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't seem to do anything. Everything works fine while testing but when online this is when the problems occur. When the remove game button is pressed it just does nothing.

Comment: Do `trace(BaseMovie);` in the function; you'll probably find it outputs `null`, meaning your first line `var BaseMovie...` is wrong (meaning `parent.parent` isn't actually the movie?)

Comment: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at EnglishGame_fla::MainTimeline/RemoveGame() is the error :s I don't see how the RemoveGame function can have an error

Comment: Followed your advice with .parent.removeChild... it works now but the only issue being that the stage is just white instead of loading main menu :s

Comment: Are you doing `new Loader(...)` somewhere to load the SWF in the first place? See [this link](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/load-external-swf-swf.html) for an example of the proper code.